# UIGetScreenImage

Tags: iphone

Is UIGetScreenImage returning an image of whatever is on the screen or is it limited to the screen shown when a camera view is displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it returns whatever's on the screen, so if you only want to capture the camera preview image, you need to crop the image UIGetScreenImage returns.

Comment: Thanks - so then this could also be a useful function to get different screen states together with a timer function to show the application in various states for documentation purposes?

Comment: for that, you'd probably just capture manual screenshots (press both buttons together)